# Install VapourSynth on Lubuntu 16.04

Tags: software-installation

I know nothing about Linux and I can't figure out how to install vapoursynth on Lubuntu 16.04 LTS (I'm a fresh user). 
Since I can't find a step by step guide on the net (they all assume I know what I'm doing), I was wandering if someone could help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install vapoursynth on lubuntu follow these steps:

Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)

Add the PPA (Personal Package Archives) for vapoursynth

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:djcj/hybrid
```

Update package lists

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install vapoursynth

```
sudo apt-get install vapoursynth
```

Comment: For those of you who encounter this problem in future, this PPA, it seems, has moved to djcj/hybrid.

Comment: @stranger_anon Thank you for the information.

Comment: @stranger_anon PPA is discontinued and installation not possible. Any Advice?

Comment: @hullunist sorry, I guess it needs to be built from source now. I haven't gone through the documentation myself, so not sure.